# Why is "an" used for nouns that start with a vowel sound

Tags: articles, history, vowels

When a noun starts with a vowel *sound*, one uses "*an*" instead of "*a*". That is reasonable since otherwise the vowels would get *mixed*.

The question is why did they "pick" "*a**n***"? There are 21 consenants in the alphabet. Is anything known why English uses "*an*" and for instance not "*al*"?

Comment: Because it's easier to say, and less likely to get confused with something else.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody “picked” anything. The word *án* simply meant “one” in Old English, just like all the other indefinite articles in related tongues from the Germanic and Romance groups.

Comment: Yeah that's why picked was between quotes. I merely meant why it turned out to be "an" and not something else.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem See [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=an).

Comment: To build on @tchrist's comment: *an* preceded *a*. So it was *a* which was ... picked. As to why *n*, because the word is related to *one* (it's more complicated than that, but that's the gist).